Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. error
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/provider/asset_flare.dart:25:23: Error: The method 'hashValues' isn't defined for the class 'AssetFlare'.

'AssetFlare' is from 'package:flare_flutter/provider/asset_flare.dart' ('../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/provider/asset_flare.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hashValues'.
int get hashCode => hashValues(bundle, name);
^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command '/Users/macos/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
next,
cd 
flutter clean

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You must modify the hashValues method call in .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/provider/asset_flare.dart as it has been replaced by Object.hash in the latest flutter 3.27 release:
int get hashCode => Object.hash(bundle, name);


This answer is not correct as it is not practical or recommended at all to modify pub cache files yourself. This can mess up the dependencies.
